# pytorch-geometric library ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, graph, pytorch, importerror, pytorch-geometric

I was trying to install pytorch-geometric but when I call
`import torch_geometric`
I'm getting the error:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`

Traceback:

```
<ipython-input-7-c36e13293883> in <module>
----> 1 import torch_geometric

D:\programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\__init__.py in <module>
      4 from .debug import is_debug_enabled, debug, set_debug
      5 import torch_geometric.data
----> 6 import torch_geometric.transforms
      7 import torch_geometric.utils
      8 

D:\programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\transforms\__init__.py in <module>
     32 from .two_hop import TwoHop
     33 from .line_graph import LineGraph
---> 34 from .laplacian_lambda_max import LaplacianLambdaMax
     35 from .generate_mesh_normals import GenerateMeshNormals
     36 from .delaunay import Delaunay

D:\programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\transforms\laplacian_lambda_max.py in <module>
----> 1 from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs, eigsh
      2 from torch_geometric.utils import get_laplacian, to_scipy_sparse_matrix
      3 
      4 
      5 class LaplacianLambdaMax(object):

D:\programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py in <module>
    114 from .dsolve import *
    115 from .interface import *
--> 116 from .eigen import *
    117 from .matfuncs import *
    118 from ._onenormest import *

D:\programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py in <module>
      9 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     10 
---> 11 from .arpack import *
     12 from .lobpcg import *
     13 

D:\programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py in <module>
     20 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     21 
---> 22 from .arpack import *

D:\programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py in <module>
     43 __all__ = ['eigs', 'eigsh', 'svds', 'ArpackError', 'ArpackNoConvergence']
     44 
---> 45 from . import _arpack
     46 import numpy as np
     47 import warnings

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

My pytorch-geometric version is:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
# pytorch-geometric         1.7.2           py37_torch_1.9.0_cu111    rusty1s
```

pytorch version:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel 
# pytorch                   1.9.0           py3.7_cuda11.1_cudnn8_0    pytorch
```

Cuda version:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver     
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation                                                                              
Built on Tue_Sep_15_19:12:04_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2020                                                                 
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.74                                                                          
Build cuda_11.1.relgpu_drvr455TC455_06.29069683_0
```

Am I missing something? Has anyone here come across this issue?

Comment: Please pay attention to which tags you select for your questions. This question plainly has nothing to do with PyCUDA and should not have been tagged as such.

Comment: Also, you have left out the most important part of the error message. The traceback which raised the ImportError shows *which* library failed to load.

Comment: @talonmies edited the question. Sorry about the incorrect tag

Comment: So your `scipy` installation is missing, broken or incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

As talonmies said it had something to do with scipy installation. Didn't work on reinstalling or upgrading or using pip. It did work on a new virtual env tho. Still not sure what was wrong in the previous env